# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens"

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I am making a request to the completions endpoint. My prompt is 1360 tokens, as verified by the Playground and the Tokenizer. I won't show the prompt as it's a little too long for this question.

Here is my request to openai in Nodejs using the openai npm package.

```
const response = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: 'text-davinci-003',
  prompt,
  max_tokens: 4000,
  temperature: 0.2
})
```

When testing in the playground my total tokens after response are 1374.

When submitting my prompt via the completions API I am getting the following error:

```
error: {
  message: "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 5360 tokens (1360 in your prompt; 4000 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.",
  type: 'invalid_request_error',
  param: null,
  code: null
}
```

If you have been able to solve this one, I'd love to hear how you did it.

Comment: Remove the "max_tokens" parameter in api call, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpANu.png

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `max_tokens` parameter is **shared** between the prompt and the completion. Tokens from the prompt and the completion all together should not exceed the token limit of a particular OpenAI model.

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them):

> Depending on the model used, requests can use up to `4097` tokens shared
> between prompt and completion. If your prompt is `4000` tokens, your
> completion can be `97` tokens at most.
>
> The limit is currently a technical limitation, but there are often
> creative ways to solve problems within the limit, e.g. condensing your
> prompt, breaking the text into smaller pieces, etc.

*Note: For counting tokens **before(!)** sending an API request, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804599/openai-api-how-do-i-count-tokens-before-i-send-an-api-request/75804651#75804651).*

**[GPT-4 and GPT-4 Turbo models:](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo)**

| LATEST MODEL | DESCRIPTION | MAX TOKENS | TRAINING DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `gpt-4-1106-preview` | **GPT-4 Turbo** The latest GPT-4 model with improved instruction following, JSON mode, reproducible outputs, parallel function calling, and more. Returns a maximum of 4,096 output tokens. This preview model is not yet suited for production traffic. [Learn more](https://openai.com/blog/new-models-and-developer-products-announced-at-devday). | 128,000 tokens | Up to Apr 2023 |
| `gpt-4-vision-preview` | **GPT-4 Turbo with vision** Ability to understand images, in addition to all other GPT-4 Turbo capabilties. Returns a maximum of 4,096 output tokens. This is a preview model version and not suited yet for production traffic. [Learn more](https://openai.com/blog/new-models-and-developer-products-announced-at-devday). | 128,000 tokens | Up to Apr 2023 |
| `gpt-4` | Currently points to `gpt-4-0613`. See [continuous model upgrades](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/continuous-model-upgrades). | 8,192 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-4-0613` | Snapshot of `gpt-4` from June 13th 2023 with improved function calling support. | 8,192 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-4-32k` | Currently points to `gpt-4-32k-0613`. See [continuous model upgrades](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/continuous-model-upgrades). | 32,768 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-4-32k-0613` | Snapshot of `gpt-4-32k` from June 13th 2023 with improved function calling support. | 32,768 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-4-0314` (Legacy) | Snapshot of `gpt-4` from March 14th 2023 with function calling support. This model version will be [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2023-06-13-updated-chat-models) on June 13th 2024. | 8,192 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-4-32k-0314` (Legacy) | Snapshot of `gpt-4-32k` from March 14th 2023 with function calling support. This model version will be [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2023-06-13-updated-chat-models) on June 13th 2024. | 32,768 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |

**[GPT-3.5 models:](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5)**

| LATEST MODEL | DESCRIPTION | MAX TOKENS | TRAINING DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-1106` | **Updated GPT 3.5 Turbo** The latest GPT-3.5 Turbo model with improved instruction following, JSON mode, reproducible outputs, parallel function calling, and more. Returns a maximum of 4,096 output tokens. [Learn more](https://openai.com/blog/new-models-and-developer-products-announced-at-devday). | 16,385 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo` | Currently points to `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613`. Will point to `gpt-3.5-turbo-1106` starting Dec 11, 2023. See [continuous model upgrades](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/continuous-model-upgrades). | 4,096 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k` | Currently points to `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613`. Will point to `gpt-3.5-turbo-1106` starting Dec 11, 2023. See [continuous model upgrades](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/continuous-model-upgrades). | 16,385 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` | Similar capabilities as `text-davinci-003` but compatible with legacy Completions endpoint and not Chat Completions. | 4,096 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613` (Legacy) | Snapshot of `gpt-3.5-turbo` from June 13th 2023. Will be [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2023-10-06-chat-model-updates) on June 13, 2024. | 4,096 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613` (Legacy) | Snapshot of `gpt-3.5-16k-turbo` from June 13th 2023. Will be [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2023-10-06-chat-model-updates) on June 13, 2024. | 16,385 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` (Legacy) | Snapshot of `gpt-3.5-turbo` from March 1st 2023. Will be [deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2023-10-06-chat-model-updates) on June 13th 2024. | 4,096 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |

**[GPT-3 models (Legacy):](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3)**

| LATEST MODEL | DESCRIPTION | MAX TOKENS | TRAINING DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `text-curie-001` | Very capable, faster and lower cost than Davinci. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `text-babbage-001` | Capable of straightforward tasks, very fast, and lower cost. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `text-ada-001` | Capable of very simple tasks, usually the fastest model in the GPT-3 series, and lowest cost. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `davinci` | Most capable GPT-3 model. Can do any task the other models can do, often with higher quality. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `curie` | Very capable, but faster and lower cost than Davinci. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `babbage` | Capable of straightforward tasks, very fast, and lower cost. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |
| `ada` | Capable of very simple tasks, usually the fastest model in the GPT-3 series, and lowest cost. | 2,049 tokens | Up to Oct 2019 |

**[GPT base models:](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-base)**

| LATEST MODEL | DESCRIPTION | MAX TOKENS | TRAINING DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `babbage-002` | Replacement for the GPT-3 `ada` and `babbage` base models. | 16,384 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |
| `davinci-002` | Replacement for the GPT-3 `curie` and `davinci` base models. | 16,384 tokens | Up to Sep 2021 |

Comment: Thanks Cervus, this cleared up a misunderstanding I had.

Comment: I have a summarization task with a long input text. Is there a workaround to handle longer input texts?

Comment: @M.HosseinRahimi Hm, I've seen a few questions regarding this. The only easy option I see is breaking the text into smaller pieces. At the end, you would have, let's say, five summaries, and then you could do a final summarization. Is this an option?

Comment: If I choose the gpt-3.5-turbo-16k model and my total token usage for a request is 5k tokens, will 4k tokens be charged at the 4k rate and the remaining 1k be charged at the 16k rate?

Comment: @thdoan I think the answer is no. Pricing depends on the model used, not on the number of tokens spent. I know what you mean, but as far as I know, the answer is no. See [Pricing](https://openai.com/pricing).

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by Reddit user 'bortlip'.

The `max_tokens` parameter defines the response tokens.

From OpenAI:

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens

> The token count of your prompt plus max_tokens cannot exceed the model's context length.

Therefore to solve the issue I subtract the token count of the prompt from the `max_tokens` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

An important note for `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` users, as per documentation:

> ChatGPT models like gpt-3.5-turbo and gpt-4 use tokens in the same way
> as older completions models, but because of their message-based
> formatting, it's more difficult to count how many tokens will be used
> by a conversation.

Please, refer to [OpenAI CookBook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb) for examples of how to deal with this if you're receiving this error because of wrongly calculated tokens. Also, the [official docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/managing-tokens) with an example.