# How to Resolve "InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is exceeded" in OpenAI API

Tags: python, openai-api

I'm encountering an error with my OpenAI API code and I'm not sure of the best way to resolve it. I'm using the "text-davinci-003" model to generate an AI response using the following code:

```
completion = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-003",
    prompt='\n'.join([f"{m['role']}: {m['content']}" for m in message_history]),
    temperature=0.7,
    max_tokens=1024,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    timeout=60,
)
```

I get the following error:

> openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length
> is 4097 tokens, however you requested 4401 tokens (3377 in your
> prompt; 1024 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or
> completion length.

I'm not sure of the best way to resolve this issue. Can you give me some advice on what I should do to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75396481/openai-gpt-3-api-error-this-models-maximum-context-length-is-4097-tokens)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vetq4G0Gsc&ab_channel=ShwetaLodha

Answer (score 0):

The `max_tokens` parameter specifies the maximum number of tokens to use for the reply. Since the "text-davinci-003" model limits the total number of tokens for both the prompt and the reply to 4,097 and you specified a limit of 1,024 tokens for the reply; your prompt must be at most 4097 - 1024 = 3,073 tokens. However, it looks like your prompt is 3,377 tokens which is what is causing your error here. You either need to reduce the number of tokens in your prompt or reduce your value for `max_tokens`.

If you'd like to compute the number of tokens in your prompt, take a look at [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804651/5711519).